# Notifications Bell icon is not displayed in Community compact header

Tags: lightning-community, partner-communities, notification

I have Customer Service template community with Stella theme. We use Partner Community License.

I want to display notifications in a compact header and selected the checkbox, but it is not displayed.

[image]

When I investigate DOM, notification element is empty, even if there is a Direct Message sent to the current user.

[image]

The logged-in user is System Admin, but the notification bell should be visible in Community Builder when activating it.
If I send the message via community it is visible in internal salesforce notifications.

[image]

I created a test Customer Account Portal community with Citizen theme in Developer Edition and there it is working just fine (Customer Community License).

Could this be related to the theme I chose (Stella)?

Comment: It can be. In our case we had to raise a support case to get the notification bell icon in community as mentioned in the documentation as it was not coming up in the header. I am not sure if that is the case with you.

Comment: @manjit5190, Thanks for the update. I`ll reach support as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created SFDC Support Case and they have enabled "Notifications in Communities" permission in my Org.
So, that was some internal permissions on SFDC side.